# How to get SourceSafe project of a version before a certain date?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

I am using SourceSafe Explorer v8.0. I imported an existing project from SourceSafe into VS 2008, worked on the project and checked it in a few times.

Now I need to import the same project into a different folder but the version of before I started working on it. I see a Get Latest" option. Where's the option to get a certain older version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do it from Visual Studio. Login into VSS with the VSS tool. Select the project in VSS - right ckick on the project and pick "Show History" - in the dialoge that pops up select the version you want and then click "Get".

Answer (score 1):

Using the gui like already suggested is indeed the easiest way, but just for completeness (and in case you would need to autmate it):

You can also use the [commandline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/661w6e3d(VS.80).aspx) to do this using the [`-V` option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cya2z0zz(VS.80).aspx):

```
> set SSDIR=\\[source safe database path]  
> set SSUSER=[source safe user]  
> set SSPWD=[source safe user password]  
> ss GET $/[path project] -R -Vd[date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the folder; show history. Pick a point in time and "Get"